# Combining two arrays side by side in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

To combine two arrays side by side, I am following the below procedure but I get

> Cannot set Property "account" of undefined.

Here is my code

```
    acs = [
    {
        "account": "Cash In Hand",
        "liabilities": 0,
        "assets": 8031597
    },
    {
        "account": "Tax Acs",
        "liabilities": 988363.72,
        "assets": 0.98
    },
    {
        "account": "Sundry Debtor",
        "liabilities": 0,
        "assets": 551
    },
    {
        "account": "Sundry Creditor",
        "liabilities": 0,
        "assets": 0
    }
];

acd: any;
acc: any;
newacc: any;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.acd = this.acs.filter(f => f.liabilities !== 0);
    this.acc = this.acs.filter(f => f.assets !== 0);

    const bigger = this.acd.length > this.acc.length ? this.acd.length : this.acc.length;

    this.newacc = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < bigger; i++) {
      if (this.acd.length > i) {
        this.newacc[i].account = this.acd[i].account;
        this.newacc[i].liabilities = this.acd[i].liabilities;
      }
      if (this.acc.length > i) {
        this.newacc[i].accounts = this.acc[i].account;
        this.newacc[i].assets = this.acc[i].assets;
      }
    }
  }
```

If I add like this `this.newacc = [{}];` I get same error for 2nd `if` that is `this.newacc[i].accounts`

What I did mistake here? Or is there any easiest way to combine two arrays side by side? These two arrays are independent in array length and do not carry any join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `push` method. The issue is that you're adding elements using `C++` syntax like.

```
 this.newacc[i].account = this.acd[i].account;
```

As I aforementioned, you could use `push` method by passing the desired *object* as parameter.

```
newacc.push({account:acd[i].account, liabilities : acd[i].liabilities });
```

```js
acs = [ { "account": "Cash In Hand", "liabilities": 0, "assets": 8031597 }, { "account": "Tax Acs", "liabilities": 988363.72, "assets": 0.98 }, { "account": "Sundry Debtor", "liabilities": 0, "assets": 551 }, { "account": "Sundry Creditor", "liabilities": 0, "assets": 0 } ];

acd = acs.filter(f => f.liabilities !== 0);
acc = acs.filter(f => f.assets !== 0);

const bigger = acd.length > acc.length ? acd.length : acc.length, newacc = [];
for (let i = 0; i < bigger; i++) {
  if (acd.length > i)
    newacc.push({account:acd[i].account, liabilities : acd[i].liabilities });
  if (acc.length > i)
    newacc.push({account:acc[i].account, assets : acc[i].assets });
}
console.log(newacc);
```

Comment: By this way it will merge array ? If it's other stuff then can you please explain me in brief ?

Comment: I have search that there is some diff in php but what diffrence in js ? Hope you don't mind it just for learn.

Comment: Can you explain in simple words ? I just want to know the core diffrence.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is purely a `Typescript` issue and nothing angular-ness in it.

Here is a fix to part of your code, the rest I think you can figure out:

```
interface accnt {
  account: string;
  liabilities: number;
  assets: number;
}

let acs = [
    {
        "account": "Cash In Hand",
        "liabilities": 0,
        "assets": 8031597
    },
    {
        "account": "Tax Acs",
        "liabilities": 988363.72,
        "assets": 0.98
    },
    {
        "account": "Sundry Debtor",
        "liabilities": 0,
        "assets": 551
    },
    {
        "account": "Sundry Creditor",
        "liabilities": 0,
        "assets": 0
    }
];

let acd: accnt[] = new Array(4);
let acc: accnt[] = new Array(4);
let newacc: accnt[] = new Array(4);

this.acd = this.acs.filter(f => f.liabilities !== 0);
this.acc = this.acs.filter(f => f.assets !== 0);
alert(JSON.stringify(this.acd));
alert(JSON.stringify(this.acc));
alert(JSON.stringify(this.newacc));

const bigger = this.acd.length > this.acc.length ? this.acd.length : this.acc.length;

for (let i = 0; i < bigger; i++) {
  if (this.acd.length > i) {
    this.newacc[i] =
      {
        account: this.acd[i].account,
        liabilities: this.acd[i].liabilities
      }
  }
  /*if (this.acc.length > i) {
    this.newacc[i].accounts = this.acc[i].account;
    this.newacc[i].assets = this.acc[i].assets;
  }*/
}

alert(JSON.stringify(this.newacc));
```